# How to create a custom float with varying bit length

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm writing a program that basically converts an int into a floating point with a twist, the user specifies how many bits are used for the exponent and mantissa part. I don't understand what the algorithm for taking a number and breaking it into an exponent and mantissa is though. If I go to an IEEE 754 Converter and type in 34, it changes it to exp 2^5 and mantissa 1.0625, but I don't understand how to get this conversion. I know what I'll do to then get the bits in the specified places, but I don't know how to get the correct bits in the first place

Comment: Is this an academic exercise or a production code? You may want to use an existing arbitrary precision math library, or otherwise you are essentially reinventing a wheel (without understanding how a wheel works).

Comment: Answering your question directly, 34(10) = 100010(2) = 1.0001(2) * 100000(2) = 1.0625(10) * 32(10) = 1.0625 * 2^5. Pardon my clumsy (n) which should have been subscripts.

Comment: To do correctly for all the cases and limits is very tricky. You should use libraries or else you risk losing bits. I have done this in a professional compiler and it certainly is one of the more challenging tasks.

Comment: @void_ptr this is academic. The part that I don't understand is the transition from binary 100010 to 1.0001. So I understand that 1.0001 * 100000, its multiplying 32 which is the largest 2^n less than 34, but how does the decimal point work in binary? I kinda get that its 0. (1/2) (1/4) (1/8) (1/16) and since the 1 is in (1/16) you get 32 * 1 + 32 * (1/16) = 34, but I don't understand how to implement this step for all numbers using an algorithm. Like I understand how it works for 34, but not how I can make it work for all numbers

Comment: Detailed answer to this question will go way outside of SO question format. Searching for "binary fraction" brings up many good links explaining the process. In short, there is no "decimal point in binary". Point separates integer and fractional portions and works the same regardless of base. Floating point notation always has mantissa with one non-zero digit integer part, hence 100010 becomes 1.0001B5. Note that since in case of binary, "non-zero digit" always means "one", the leading "1" in mantissa notation is implicit and is not actually stored (unless you deal with denormals).